# Are quasi-normal modes in black hole perturbation theory the same as resonances in Quantum Mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, black-holes, perturbation-theory, resonance, normal-modes

When we evaluate [quasi-normal modes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasinormal_mode) in black hole [perturbation theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perturbation_theory) (also [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasinormal_mode#Mathematical_Physics)), by solving the [Regge-wheeler potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regge%E2%80%93Wheeler%E2%80%93Zerilli_equations), is it same as solving the [Schrödinger equation for a barrier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectangular_potential_barrier) and finding resonances which are also complex eigenvalues.

Comment: What do you mean by "the same"? The problems can certainly be phrased in a mathematically very similar way, and therefore solved in a similar way.

Comment: Yes, I meant this mathematical similarity. For example it is clear that QNM can neither be a bound state nor a continuum scattering state, so what is left is the resonant state. Of course black hole is a ramification of a classical theory GR and Quantum Mechanics comes as solutions to schrodinger equation. When we solve regge-wheeler equation (which is schrodinger (1D) like) for QNM is it not same as solving schrodinger equation for resonant states of a barrier?